# Horizontal swipe slider with jQuery and touch devices support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, css

I need to make a product slider like this ( see red area ) swipe slider with momentum.

It should work on Desktop, iPad and Mobile browser. Do you know any jquery/jquery mobile plugin to achieve this.

[image]

The effect I want is almost similar to this http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_thumbnail_scroller.html (but it's not touch compatible)

and exactly like "Top 25" section in Apple's iPad app named "Trailers"

[image]

Comment: FYI: Removed the jquery-mobile tag, since the OP commented in _Phill Pafford_'s answer, that he's not using jquery-mobile in the project.

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion [**iosSlider**](http://iosscripts.com/iosslider-jquery-horizontal-slider-for-iphone-ipad-safari/) is amazing. It works in almost any device and it is well documented. It's free for personal usage, but for commercial sites license costs $20.

Also a great option is [**touchCarousel**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/) or [**RoyalSlider**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) from same author. These two have everything you'll need, **but also not free** and have a price of $10-12

Answer (score 16):

I would also recommend http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

BUT if you're not digging on that try this plugin

http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/

it works very well and defaults to a horizontal slide bar on desktop -- it's not as elegant on desktop as iscroll-4 is, but it works very well on touch devices

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: and I also need desktop compatibility

Comment: I have iScroll implemented on 2 different websites and neither of them require the site to be viewed in full screen in order for the scrolling to work -- and it works just great on desktop and touch devices, fwiw -- and this is also true of the touchslider method

Comment: iScroll was already mentioned by dSquared and it has problem with form elements if they are on same page

Answer (score 15):

If I was you, I would implement my own solution based on the event specs. Basically, what swipe is - it's handling of touch down, touch move, touch up events. here is excerpt of my own lib for handling iPhone touch events:

```
touch_object.prototype.handle_touchstart = function(e){
    if (e.targetTouches.length != 1){
        return false;
    }
    this.obj.style.zIndex = 100;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.startX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - this.geometry.x;
    this.startY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - this.geometry.y;
    /* adjust for left /top */
    this.bind_handler('touchmove');
    this.bind_handler('touchend');
}
touch_object.prototype.handle_touchmove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.targetTouches.length != 1){
        return false;
    }
    var x=e.targetTouches[0].pageX - this.startX;
    var y=e.targetTouches[0].pageY - this.startY;
    this.move(x,y);

}
touch_object.prototype.handle_touchend = function(e){
    this.obj.style.zIndex = 10;
    this.unbind_handler('touchmove');
    this.unbind_handler('touchend');
}
```

I used that code to "move things around". But, instead of moving, you can create your own algorithm for e.g. triggering redirect to some other location, or you can use that move to "move/swipe" the element, on which the swipe is on to other location.

so, it really helps to understand basics of how things work and then create more complicated solutions. this might help as well.

I used this, to create my solution:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried iosSlider? It can do exactly what you need.

http://iosscripts.com/iosslider-jquery-horizontal-slider-for-iphone-ipad-safari/

Comment: This plugin is free only for personal/non-profit use, it costs $20 for single domain, imo it's way too much. I'd recommend using iScroll, or paid touchcarousel/royalslider from CodeCanyon.

Comment: @tMagwell You believe that $20 is too much? I'll bet you spent more than that on coffee this week alone. For something that will save you writing it yourself, I fail to see how that is 'too much'. Sorry for the rant, but I think us developers need to get our priorities straight sometimes. Let's reward the hard work some people are doing out there - not everything will run under the free / open source ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at iScroll v4 here: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

It may not be jQuery, but it works on Desktop Mobile, and iPad quite well; I've used it on many projects and combined it with jQuery.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

This one could fit your need:
http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/

Add [jquery Touchwipe](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library) for touch support

Then in the configuration add

```
scroll : {
wipe: true
}
```

Comment: For someone looking at this thread, visiting the following links to find the library:
`https://github.com/Codeinwp/carouFredSel-jQuery`
`http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/48/`
`http://docs.themeisle.com/article/499-getting-started-with-the-caroufredsel-jquery-plugin`

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) from WooThemes? I've used it on several recent projects with great success. It's touch enabled too so it will work on both mouse-based browsers as well as touch-based browsers in iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, hope it helps
http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/

Comment: Sorry, I replied form my phone and didn't realized it was already mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I have made somthink like this for one of my website accualy in developpement.

I have used [StepCarousel](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm) for the caroussel because it's the only one I found that can accept different image size in the same carrousel.

In addition to this to add the touch swipe effect, I have used [jquery.touchswipe](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library) plugin;

And stepcarousel move panel rigth or left with a fonction so I can make :

```
$("#slider-actu").touchwipe({
    wipeLeft: function() {stepcarousel.stepBy('slider-actu', 3);},
    wipeRight: function() {stepcarousel.stepBy('slider-actu', -3);},
    min_move_x: 20
});
```

You can view the actual render at [this page](http://suzannegoyat.com/galerie.php)

Hope that help you.

Answer (score 1):

Ive found another: http://swipejs.com/

seems to work nicely however I encounter an issue with it when paired with bootstrap on the OS X version of Chrome. If total cross-browser compatibility isn't an issue, then you're golden.

Comment: I'd say this is truly the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar and uses jQuery mobile http://www.irinavelychko.com/tutorials/jquery-mobile-gallery

And, the demo of it http://demo.irinavelychko.com/tuts/jqm-dialog-gallery.html

Comment: Both links are broken

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery scroll view (demo [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-nested.html)). [Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview) is the git hub repository for that experimental project. Look at their html to see what files need to be included and what attributes to add to the elements you want to be scrollable.

I have used this to be able to scroll div elements horizontally on touch devices.

Comment: but it's based on jquery mobile. and i'm not using it for the project

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the following:

- [jQuery Mobile Carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/) ([github](https://github.com/blackdynamo/jQuery-Mobile-Carousel))
- [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

I realize this is not a jQuery solution, but [Sencha Touch framework](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) is pretty good for building your target UI. Example (click the *Carousel* sidebar link):
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Comment: I hope you'd add some visual clues that that particular area can slide upon touch; maybe adding a left / right arrows? It might sound a bit boring but it'd generate a supposedly better _visual affordance_.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Portfoliojs jQuery plugin: http://portfoliojs.com

This plugin supports Touch Devices, Desktops and Mobile Browsers. Also, It has pre-loading feature.

Answer (score 0):

With my experiance the best open source option will be [UIKIT](http://getuikit.com/index.html) with its [uikit slider component](http://getuikit.com/docs/slider.html).
and it is very easy to implement for example in your case you could do something like this.

```
<div data-uk-slider>
<div class="uk-slider-container">
    <ul class="uk-slider uk-grid-width-medium-1-4"> // width of the elements
        <li>...</li> //slide elements
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```