# How to show a picture after clicking the thumbnail using Javascript not jQuery?

Tags: javascript, photo-gallery

I have found the answer on how to do the same thing with jQuery [How to show/hide big image by clicking on thumbnails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121681/how-to-show-hide-big-image-by-clicking-on-thumbnails), but I would like to know how to do the same thing with just Javascript.

In jQuery there you can use $(this) to specify that the image that you clicked on should become the bigger image, but is there an equivalent without jQuery?

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__01.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__02.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__03.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__04.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__05.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__06.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__07.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__08.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__09.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__10.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__11.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__12.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__13.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__14.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__15.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__16.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__17.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="thumbs">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__18.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
</ol>
<div id="gallery"><img src="images/thumbnails/t__01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I was thinking that I could link the li images to a image id using only CSS, but that would mean that if I pressed back, then it would go back to the previous image instead of the previous page.

One way of doing it may be to use  on each image. The changeImage() would then change the current larger image to the one clicked. If the thumb clicked in the active image, then nothing happens. Else change the #gallery img src to the clicked thumbs' src.

I don't know how to convert that into code though.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, just `this`. Please add more details like your markup and code you already tried, then we can give you more specific advice.

Comment: Added details to the post

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, why did you tag your question with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vanilla-js version will not be so different from the jQuery version. If you add a click listener with `addEventListener`, the clicked element will be available as `this`:

```
var large = document.getElementById('gallery').firstChild;
// another option:
// var large = document.querySelector('#gallery img');

var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbs');
// another option:
// var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbs');

for(var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++) {
    thumbs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        large.src = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
    }, false);
}
```

You can use a single event handler on your `<ol>`, instead of one per `<li>`. This example assumes a `thumbs-container` class on the `<ol>`:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.thumbs-container');
container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    large.src = e.target.src;
}, false);
```

Be aware that my code examples need a few tweaks to work cross-browser, particularly for IE<=8.

Comment: It's worth noting that getElementsByClassName() has compatibility implications [quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements)

Comment: @Zachdev Yes, if you decide to use no library, you'll have to handle the cross-browser issues yourself. (Did you write that comment before I added the last sentence?).

Comment: I've added    <script type="text/javascript">
    var large = document.getElementById('gallery').firstChild;
    var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbs');
    for(var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++) {
        thumbs[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            large.src = this.src;
        }, false);
    }
   </script> before the </body>. The gallery image src says undefined. What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks it worked, but why didn't the script I used before work? Why did it return undefined?

Comment: because apparently `this` in that context is the `li` that you attach your event listener to

Comment: @j03w You're right, my mistake. I'll fix the answer later, on mobile right now.

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, there were a few mistakes in my code, I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a unique id to each of your `li` tags.

```
<li class="thumbs" id="unique1" onclick="function_name(this.id)">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/t__01.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
```

javascript code here

```
function function_name(test_id){
    var _img = document.getElementById("test_id");
    //code to show the corresponding image
}
```