# `this` and $(this) in ES6 module are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, this

I was trying to add the functionality of toggleImage in a gallery and checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121681/how-to-show-hide-big-image-by-clicking-on-thumbnails) thread and [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/1/) provided in one of the answers, but got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined` in the console.

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
   <figure>
     <img data-src="/assets/images/small/one.jpg">
     <a data-href="/assets/images/one.jpg">
   </figure>
   <figure>
     <img data-src="/assets/images/small/two.jpg">
     <a data-href="/assets/images/two.jpg">
   </figure>
   <figure>
     <img data-src="/assets/images/small/three.jpg">
     <a data-href="/assets/images/three.jpg">
   </figure>
</div>

  <div class="modal">
    <div class="">
      <img class="modal__image" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="modal__close">X</div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript that works:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

class ToggleImage {
  constructor() {
    this.thumbnail = $('#gallery img')
    this.modalImage = $('.modal__image')
    this.passHref()
  }

  passHref() {
    this.thumbnail.click(e => {
      const href = $(e.target).siblings().attr('data-href')
      this.modalImage.attr('src', href)
      e.preventDefault
      return false
    })
  }  
}

const toggleImage = new ToggleImage()
```

As you can see, `var href = $(this)` was changed to `$(e.target).siblings()`. Before this change I'd tried to use just `this` or just `e.target` with getAttribute() and non-arrow function, or add `const that = this` before line `const href` and use `that` instead, but none of them worked. May I know why?

And, so far the click event is bundled with the action code. But because I hope to separate the action from the event, $(e.target) doesn't fit in this case.

```
class ToggleImage {
  constructor() {
    this.thumbnail = $('#gallery img')
    this.modalImage = $('.modal__image')
    this.passHref()
    this.event()   // added
  }

  event() {
    this.thumbnail.click(this.passHref)
  }

  passHref() {
     // some code other than $(e.target)...
  }  
}
```

Comment: `this` and `e.target` are Element objects, hence do not have a `siblings()` method. Therefore you need to use either `$(this)` or `$(e.target)` - preferably the former - to place those Elements within a jQuery object to be able to call jQuery methods on them.

Comment: Your use of an arrow function is directly blocking what you want to do.

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `this.thumbnail.click(function(e) { const href = $(this).attr('data-href'); console.log(href); }` would be `undefined`. May I know what's the jQuery methods you mentioned here? If change `this.thumbnail = $('#gallery img')` to `this.thumbnail = $('#gallery figure')` as well.

Answer (score 1):

To further clarify the comments, here you can see how `this` works inside both a normal function and an arrow function.

```js
console.log('global scope this: ' + this);

$('button').click(e => console.log('arrow function this: ' + this));

$('button').click(function(e) { 
  console.log('function this: ' + this); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Just to clarify, `this` in an arrow function will be the same as `this` outside the arrow function. In the code above the parent scope is global, where `this` is undefined.

Comment: The thing is when it was normal function, `const href = this.getAttribute('data-href')` would be `null` and `this.modalImage` would be `undefined` and that's why in the post I said non-arrow function didn't work either.

Comment: I'd suggest you continue with the solution you have, use an arrow-function and `e.target` - you have a working solution, your question was why.

Answer (score 1):

in your component,'this' is the Object of 'ToggleImage'. you can't use $(this) because here js understands '$(this)' as '$(ToggleImage)'