# How to call JavaScript in WebView from iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have an edge animation called `index.html` (5 animated slides ) locally stored in iOS app. I load that html in a UIWebView, and I want to send message to the edge animation to show specific slide in the WebView. How do I do this?

My JavaScript file is named `index_edgeActions.js`. This is the code:

```
//Edge symbol: 'Nav_Bar'
(function(symbolName) {
    Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_go_to_slide}", "click", function(sym, e) {
        var myPos = sym.getComposition().getStage().getPosition();
        var myTimeline = sym.getComposition().getStage();
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == 1) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(999);
                }
                if (myPos < 500) {
                    myTimeline.play(1);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 2) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 1000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(1499);
                }
                if (myPos < 1000) {
                    myTimeline.play(501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 3) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 1500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(1999);
                }
                if (myPos < 1500) {
                    myTimeline.play(1001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 4) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 2000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(2499);
                }
                if (myPos < 2000) {
                    myTimeline.play(1501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 5) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 2500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(2999);
                }
                if (myPos < 2500) {
                    myTimeline.play(2001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 6) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 3000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(3499);
                }
                if (myPos < 3000) {
                    myTimeline.play(2501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 7) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 3500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(3999);
                }
                if (myPos < 3500) {
                    myTimeline.play(3001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 8) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 4000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(4499);
                }
                if (myPos < 4000) {
                    myTimeline.play(3501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 9) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 4500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(4999);
                }
                if (myPos < 4500) {
                    myTimeline.play(4001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 10) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 5000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(5499);
                }
                if (myPos < 5000) {
                    myTimeline.play(4501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 11) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 5500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(5999);
                }
                if (myPos < 5500) {
                    myTimeline.play(5001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 12) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 6000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(6499);
                }
                if (myPos < 6000) {
                    myTimeline.play(5501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 13) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 6500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(6999);
                }
                if (myPos < 6500) {
                    myTimeline.play(6001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 14) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 7000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(7499);
                }
                if (myPos < 7000) {
                    myTimeline.play(6501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 15) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 7500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(7999);
                }
                if (myPos < 7500) {
                    myTimeline.play(7001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 16) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 8000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(8499);
                }
                if (myPos < 8000) {
                    myTimeline.play(7501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 17) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 8500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(8999);
                }
                if (myPos < 8500) {
                    myTimeline.play(8001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 18) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 9000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(9499);
                }
                if (myPos < 9000) {
                    myTimeline.play(8501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 19) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 9500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(9999);
                }
                if (myPos < 9500) {
                    myTimeline.play(9001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 20) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 10000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(10499);
                }
                if (myPos < 10000) {
                    myTimeline.play(9501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 21) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 10500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(10999);
                }
                if (myPos < 10500) {
                    myTimeline.play(10001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 22) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 11000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(11499);
                }
                if (myPos < 11000) {
                    myTimeline.play(10501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 23) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 11500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(11999);
                }
                if (myPos < 11500) {
                    myTimeline.play(11001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 24) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 12000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(12499);
                }
                if (myPos < 12000) {
                    myTimeline.play(11501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 25) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 12500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(12999);
                }
                if (myPos < 12500) {
                    myTimeline.play(12001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 26) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 13000) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(13499);
                }
                if (myPos < 13000) {
                    myTimeline.play(12501);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 27) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos > 13500) {
                    myTimeline.playReverse(13999);
                }
                if (myPos < 13500) {
                    myTimeline.play(13001);
                }
            });
        } else if (x == 28) {
            $(function() {
                if (myPos < 14000) {
                    myTimeline.play(13501);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Only Slides From 1-28");
        }
    });
```

and use this code in Xcode Action

```
NSString* javascriptCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"index_edgeActions.js"];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCommand];
[hema stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getElementById(12)"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in iOS, UIWebview has a method to execute a javascript function:

for example:

```
[_myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunc();"];
```

Comment: Take a look a this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098107/horizontal-swipe-slider-with-jquery-and-touch-devices-support

Comment: Or you can even send a gesture

Comment: aim sorry for disturb i have edge animation (index.html+index_edge.js+index_edgeActions.js+index_edgepreload.js) how to send action from objective c code to the html or js files to tell them to perform move to specific slide

Comment: keep in your mind that there is one html file contain 5 slides

Comment: i update my question can you help me now ? and is my code correct ?           NSString* javascriptCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"index_edgeActions.js"]; [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCommand]; [hema stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getElementById(12)"]